# Easy fingering for C6-D6-E6 on tenor saxophone

Tags: fingering, saxophone, woodwinds

I am looking for an easy fingering for C6-D6-E6 on the tenor saxophone.

I know there are different fingerings for each not possible on the sax and I did study the [ultimate fingering chart](http://www.bigbangstudio.ch/Down/Grifftabelle_Version_E-1.0.pdf), which is an excellent resource.

Yet, a friend recommended me to avoid using the palm keys because they kind of slow you down, to which I agree. I also kind of feel like the sax is slipping from my hands when I play the D6, there is no "frontal support". Therefore I am trying to find another grip for D6 without a palm key, so not like this:

[image]

I do prefer to use this fingering for E6 because it is easy and fast to continue up the register this way:
[image]

So my main question is: is there any grip for D6 without using the palm key?

Comment: As a clarification, the octave numbers refer to absolute (midi) octaves.

Comment: Have you tried adding palm key risers to your instrument?   I have big hands and they make the palm keys much easier to play for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but it's actually lacking in substance, in my opinion.

Also, your reference manual is a good one but it's incomplete as well. I only use it for multiphonics personally. In my opinion, [this](https://www.wfg.woodwind.org/sax/sax_alt_2.html) is a much better resource of alternate fingerings. My teacher recommended playing C + palm D for quick switches between C6 and D6, claiming that it's a bit off but won't be noticed in a quick progression. On my horn it's *way off*, so I don't do it. Personally, I just play the first harmonic on D5 (which is D6), just like [LS97](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/12781/ls97) suggested to you. That is subject to how large the opening on your mouthpiece is, how hard the reed is and so on. I doubt you would be able to get the first harmonic on D5 if your mouthpiece has a small baffle and your reed is below 3.5 strength.

All common fingerings feature at least 1 palm key.

P.S. It would be funny if you were struggling with this progression because you were learning to play a certain passage from Pink Panther at 120BPM (that's when I first had to deal with this problem myself).

Answer (score 1):

I think what your asking for is an alternative fingering for the palm D. Unfortunately, that's a discomfort you'll need to learn to overcome.

Comment: Wouldn't fingering a low D, Bb, or A produce a high D as an overtone? Not exactly what a beginner is looking for, and no guarantee on the tone, but shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Playing D with the correct fingering should be easy enough.  If you think this is awkward or slow you should try the clarinet, or for some real fun, the bassoon.  :)  Trying to get it some other way is going to not be worth the effort and not sound right and probably be out of tune.

Using the alternate fingering for E (with the jump key) should be used judiciously in my opinion as well, basically I think of it as a bridge between the altissimo register and the "normal" register.  If I'm not going to or coming from altissimo, I'm using "palm" E every time.

Comment: It's almost impossible to play C6->D6->E6 at 120BPM without using an alternate fingering for D6 (according to my teacher).